# Creating portfolios depending on 2 variables with SAS

Tags: sorting, sas, stock, portfolio

I am actually new to SAS and would like form portfolios between the intersection of 2 variables from my spreadsheet.

Basically, I have an excel file called 'Up' with variables in it like 'month, company, BM, market cap usd)
I would like to sort for each month my data: the size (descending) and then BM (descending). I would like to create 4 size portfolios according to P25, P50 and P75 with the first size portfolio being above P75 (for each month) and so on. Then for each size portfolio that was create recreating  4 new portfolios in function of 'BM' and also with P25, P50, and P75.

Could someone help me and display me the SAS code and the way to add it to my existing 'Up' file (name of the sheet is also named 'up')

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired output and show us what you have tried already. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 0):

So I agree with the comment, this is not asked well.  However, it is a common problem to solve and somewhat fun.  So here goes:

First I'm going to just make up some data.  Google search how to read Excel in SAS.  It's easy.

1000 companies with a random `SIZE` and `BM` value.

```
data companies(drop=c);
format company $12.;
do c=1 to 1000;
    company = catt("C_",put(c,z4.));
    size = ceil(100*ranuni(1));
    BM = ceil(100*ranuni(1));
    output;
end;
run;
```

So I'm assuming you just want equal amounts in these 4 groups.  You don't want to estimate percentiles based on a distribution or KDE.  For this, `PROC RANK` works well.

```
proc rank data=companies out=companies descending groups=4;
var size;
ranks p_size;
run;
```

We now have a variable `P_SIZE` that is values `0,1,2,3` based on the descending order of `SIZE`.

Sort the portfolios by that `P_SIZE` value.

```
proc sort data=companies;
by p_size;
run;
```

Now run `PROC RANK` again, this time using a `BY` statement with `P_SIZE`,  ranking on `BM`, and creating `P_SIZE_BM`.

```
proc rank data=companies out=companies descending groups=4;
var bm;
by p_size;
ranks p_size_bm;
run;
```

`P_SIZE_BM` now contains values `0,1,2,3` for EACH value of `P_SIZE`.

Sort the data and see how it comes out:

```
proc sort data=companies;
by p_size p_size_bm;
run;
```